# TeamViewer. Cannot Control remote Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have installed TeamViewer on Ubuntu 18 desktop in the lab. On my laptop, I can connect remotely to the Ubuntu machine. However, I only see the desktop and cannot do any operation. I can move the cursor around the desktop but cannot do anything, mouse click etc.. doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What version Ubuntu? What version Teamviewer?

Comment: TeamViewer 14 running on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Teamviewer 15.3 can be download from https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/linux/

Comment: Thank you, v15 really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Please install TeamViewer 15.3 from [here](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/linux/) and retest.